# in JPA is it possible to merge an entity using a non pk field to update the row

Tags: java, jpa

so imagine you have entity User with fields id (PK), ssn (unique) , name ,lastname and birthdate

now, from another source  I have all fields except the id ,

so I would like to do something like

```
User  newInformationUser = new User();
newInformationUser.setSsn(feed.getSsn());
newInformationUser.setName(feed.getName());
...
// make the following sentence to use ssn for updating the data
entityManager.merge(newInformationUser);
```

I'd appreciate your comments , possible ? not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `merge` with a new entity. Merge is for an entity that already exists, for when you change the field of an existing entity. If you don't know the `id`, then you would use another field to lookup the existing entity.

```
User user = em.find( .. somehow ... );
user.setSsn(...);
em.merge(user);
```

Ask yourself this: how would the `EntityManager` know which entity to merge the new information into?

Comment: yes I know,  but it is expensive to look up the entity, what I am looking for is a way to JPA   to use this other unique field in the WHERE clause when I do not have the pk id

Comment: You will have to use the other field to lookup the original entity. If that lookup is expensive you can try putting an index on that field.